# How do I replace a substring within a string, but only if substring is matched within a regex group?

Tags: postgresql

I need to extract information from a malformed json-formatted string. Due to an error, all quotes have been stripped, so instead of:

```
{"receipt_type":"Production","adam_id":1233,"app_item_id":1233,"more":[{"h":234}]}
```

I have:

```
 {receipt_type:Production,adam_id:1233,app_item_id:1233,more:[{h:234}]}
```

Using

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("transactionReceipt", ':', '":"'),',','","'),'{','{"'),'}','"}'),':"[{',':[{'), ']"}', ']}')
```

I can get mostly fine json, HOWEVER this incorrectly turns `"receipt_creation_date":"2021-01-24 03:11:53 Etc/GMT"` into `"receipt_creation_date":"2021-01-24 03":"11":"53 Etc/GMT"`

Using

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("transactionReceipt", ':', '":"'),',','","'),'{','{"'),'}','"}'),':"[{',':[{'), ']"}', ']}'),'\d\d\"\:\"\d\d\"\:\"\d\d','','g')
```

I can match the 03":"11":"53 and remove it totally, yielding correct JSON.

But I want to retain the time, meaning that I swap ":" with : but ONLY if ":" is within the regex pattern of `'\d\d\"\:\"\d\d\"\:\"\d\d'`?

Thank you!

edit: a complete malformed record (it's actually an IAP transaction receipt from Apple) looks like

`{receipt_type:Production,adam_id:123456789,app_item_id:123456789,bundle_id:example.app.yo,application_version:101,download_id:123456789,version_external_identifier:123456789,receipt_creation_date:2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT,receipt_creation_date_ms:1584634707000,receipt_creation_date_pst:2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles,request_date:2020-03-19 16:18:28 Etc/GMT,request_date_ms:1584634708876,request_date_pst:2020-03-19 09:18:28 America/Los_Angeles,original_purchase_date:2020-02-28 17:55:33 Etc/GMT,original_purchase_date_ms:1582912533000,original_purchase_date_pst:2020-02-28 09:55:33 America/Los_Angeles,original_application_version:101,in_app:[{quantity:1,product_id:com.eample.iap.id,transaction_id:123456789,original_transaction_id:123456789,purchase_date:2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT,purchase_date_ms:1584634707000,purchase_date_pst:2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles,original_purchase_date:2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT,original_purchase_date_ms:1584634707000,original_purchase_date_pst:2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles,is_trial_period:false}]}`

Comment: Geez. Why can't Apple simply follow established standards and provide that as a valid  JSON structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two nested regexp_replace() calls:

- first to enclose all keys with double quotes
- then to enclose all values with double quotes

```sql
with data (input) as (
  values ('{receipt_type:Production,adam_id:1233,app_item_id:1233,more:[{h:234}]}')
)
select regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(input, '(\w+)(:)', '"\1"\2', 'g'),
          '(:)(\w+)(,|})', '\1"\2"\3', 'g')
from data;
```

returns:

```json
{"receipt_type":"Production","adam_id":"1233","app_item_id":"1233","more":[{"h":"234"}]}
```

If you want have the integers without quotes, you could run a third `regexp_replace` that removes the quotes from integers with quotes:

```
regexp_replace(..., '"([0-9]+)"', '\1', 'g')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I wrapped the three replaces, but it results in this:`{"receipt_creation_date":2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT,"receipt_creation_date_ms":1584634707000,...}` so the date/time string doesn't get quotes for receipt_creation_date :(

Comment: @phikappa: you probably need a first step that only applies to patterns for timestamps

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I added an extension (not sure what to call it) to your answer in  a revised one of my own - if you have any feedback, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

the answer by @a_horse_with_no_name got me onto the right path. way I solved it was to change my previous attempt `REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("transactionReceipt", ':', '":"'),',','","'),'{','{"'),'}','"}'),':"[{',':[{'), ']"}', ']}'),'\d\d\"\:\"\d\d\"\:\"\d\d','','g')` 
with this:
`REGEXP_REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace("transactionReceipt", ':', '":"'),',','","'),'{','{"'),'}','"}'),':"[{',':[{'), ']"}', ']}'),'(\d\d)(":")(\d\d)(":")(\d\d)','\1:\3:\5','g')`

note the parenthesis enclosing the blocks of (\d\d) & (":") so I can backreference them in the replacement regex. this gave correct JSON, albeit with quotes around integers. I then wrapped everything in the third component `regexp_replace(..., '"([0-9]+)"', '\1', 'g')` to yield perfect json.

Comment: Maybe you should give us the data (a few records) and we can possibly provide a regex that tackles the underlying problem - all of those `REPLACE(REPLACE(...`s hurt my eyes! :-) @a_horse_with_no_name's answer was pretty good - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d1585d2abcc99f3f87d8a64b39920f8d). p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Thank you @Vérace ! I know all the replaces are a bit cumbersome, the issue with the first part of @a_horse_with_no_name was that it leaves some values without quotes, like so `"request_date":2020-03-19 16:18:28 Etc/GMT` but yeah not super elegant. I added an example record below

Comment: Where is the sample record that you "added below"?

Comment: actually edited my original question with the example

Answer (score 0):

I have extensively revised my answer (and deleted the old one!) - it's quite simple really - just requires a **lot** of patience and f&*#-ing (that's fiddling) about - regexes really are fussy!

@a_horse_with_no_name's answer gives you this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fae6116d595c6cf1213e9aa4d1862428)):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( regexp_replace(
          regexp_replace(j_str, '(\w+)(:)', '"\1"\2', 'g'),
          '(:)(\w+)(,|})', '\1"\2"\3', 'g'), 198)
from test;
```

Result:

```
.... 9","receipt_creation_date":2020-03-19 "16":"18":27 Etc/GMT,"rec...
```

`SUBSTR` is for testing.

So, the challenge is to convert

```
...te":2020-03-19 "16":"18":27 Etc/GMT,"r...
```

into

```
...te":"2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT","r...
```

which I did in the following way:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(
  REGEXP_REPLACE
  (
    REGEXP_REPLACE
    (
      REGEXP_REPLACE
      (
        j_str, 
        '(\w+)(:)', 
        '"\1"\2', 'g'
      ),
      '(:)(\w+)(,|})', '\1"\2"\3', 'g'
    ),
    '(":)(\d{4,4}-\d{2,2}-\d{2,2}) "(\d{2,2})":"(\d{2,2})":(\d{2,2}) (\w+/\w+),"',
    '\1"\2 \3:\4:\5 \6","', 'g' 
  ), 200
)
FROM test;
```

Result (line breaks inserted for legibilty):

```
,"receipt_creation_date":"2020-03-19 16:18:27Etc/GMT",

"receipt_creation_date_ms":"1584634707000",

"receipt_creation_date_pst":"2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles",
"request_date":"2020-03-19 16:18:28 Etc/GMT",

"request_date_ms":"1584634708876","request_date_pst":"2020-03-19 09:18:28 America/Los_Angeles",

"original_purchase_date":"2020-02-28 17:55:33 Etc/GMT",

"original_purchase_date_ms":"1582912533000",

"original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-02-28 09:55:33 America/Los_Angeles",

"original_application_version":"101","in_app":[{"quantity":"1","product_id":com.eample.iap.id,"transaction_id":"123456789","original_transaction_id":"123456789",

"purchase_date":"2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT",

"purchase_date_ms":"1584634707000","purchase_date_pst":"2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles",

"original_purchase_date":"2020-03-19 16:18:27 Etc/GMT",

"original_purchase_date_ms":"1584634707000",

"original_purchase_date_pst":"2020-03-19 09:18:27 America/Los_Angeles","is_trial_period":"false"}]}
```

Every date appears to be in the correct format! As mentioned in my deleted answer, regexes can become quite complex quite soon - for a look at what a regex for ISO-8601 dates looks like, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143070/javascript-regex-iso-datetime) - make yourself a coffee first!